# How to limit PhpCsFixer to staged files?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, php-cs-fixer

I'm using *PhpCsFixer* on a project using *Composer* and *Git* for the version control.

When I launch PhpCsFixer, the tool updates **all** files. I'm searching solutions :

- to limit fixes on the **modified** files,
- to limit fixes on the **staged** files.

I already tried to create a command via composer `composer fix-staged-files` but it affects all files.

```
   ...
   "scripts": {
        ...
        "fix-staged-files": "php-cs-fixer fix --config=quality/.php_cs.dist --allow-risky yes ",
        ...
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a section explaining how to check only changed files: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v3.0.0/doc/usage.rst#using-php-cs-fixer-on-ci

But I've never used it, why not simply replying on cache? When you run fixer 1st time it builds a cache and every consecutive run checks only files that were modified since previous run.

Comment: Because application doesn't respect the rules. Each time a team member updates a file, he shall now respect the rules before his commits.

Answer (score 1):

**command:**

```bash
$ php ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --using-cache=no \
    --config .php-cs-fixer.dist.php  --diff --allow-risky=yes \
    --path-mode=intersection -- \
    $(git diff --name-only  --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB \
        $(git cherry origin/master | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')..HEAD)
```

**or alias style:**

```bash
# /etc/bash.bashrc

function ff(){
    php ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --using-cache=no --config .php-cs-fixer.dist.php  --diff --allow-risky=yes --path-mode=intersection -- $(git diff --name-only  --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB $(git cherry origin/master | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')..HEAD)
}
export -f ff
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).